# bash wildcard expansion with a set construct

Tags: bash, perl

Bash wildcard expansion.

I have a direcotry with three files in it. I want to use wilcar expansion to match program.c and program.o

```
casper@casper-PC ~
$ ls -ltr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 casper None 0 Apr 12 18:31 perl_lwp
-rw-r--r--  1 casper None 0 Apr 25 00:14 program.o
-rw-r--r--  1 casper None 0 Apr 25 00:14 program.c
-rw-r--r--  1 casper None 0 Apr 25 00:14 program.log
```

This does not work.

```
casper@casper-PC ~ 
$ ls -ltr | egrep program.[co]
```

Nor does this work.

```
 casper@casper-PC ~ 
$ ls -ltr | egrep program.?
```

This does not work

```
casper@casper-PC ~
$ grep -r program.?
```

this does work  - but I wanted to use bash brace expansion, not perl.

```
casper@casper-PC ~
$ ls -ltr | perl -nle 'print /(program.[co])/'
program.o
program.c
```

However I thought it strange that it matches both of them because I thought that the set construct would match o or c and then stop once it matched

Comment: No need for `grep`: `ls -l program.{c,o}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `set -x` to see what is happening.  Since you are using wildcards (*glob constructs*) outside quotes, **the shell** expands the filenames *before* `egrep` gets run.

If you want to pass patterns to a program, *enclose them inside 'single quotes'*.

Don't confuse globbing with regular expressions - they are different pattern matching regimes.  For example:, in regular expressions `?` means "zero or more of the preceding pattern", whereas in globbing it means *exactly* one character.

`program.?` in a regular expression means "program" followed by an optional single  character (`.` means one of any character except newline) *somewhere in the string*.

`program.?` in globbing means "program." followed by one single character.

`egrep` takes regular expressions, not glob constructs.

This is also possibly an unnecessary use of both `ls` and `egrep`, just use `echo`:

```
echo program.[co]
   program.c program.o
echo program.?
   program.c program.o
```

This works because `echo` is a shell built-in and the shell does globbing (and is generally more efficient than calling an external program like `ls`).

Now your Perl snippet worked for two reasons.  One:  you enclosed the pattern inside single quotes, which you didn't do for the `egrep`.

Two:  you just happened to pick the *only* pattern which is the same in regular expressions and globbing - the [ ] *character-class* notation (although there are even differences here).  The /.../ notation in Perl invokes the regular expression match (`m`) operator by default.

You expected the Perl match to stop on the first match, but the `-nl` options means that it performs the `print` statement in a loop for each line in standard-input, which comes from the pipe.

BTW, Perl also has the built-in function `glob()`.

```
echo *|perl -nle 'print glob("program.[co]")'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding end of the line anchor and also put the regex inside quotes. Note that grep uses regex to find strings not glob.

```
ls -ltr | grep 'program\.[co]$'
```

Comment: you may try glob `ls -ltr *program.[co]`

Comment: Or even `echo program.[co]`